# Incorrectly Displayed Fields in Customizer WordPress (created three but displayed one)

Tags: wordpress

I created the Options panel in WordPress customizer.php:

```
// Add theme options panel.
    $wp_customize->add_panel(
     'anvitest-lite', array(
     'title'           => esc_html__( 'Theme Options', 'anvitest-lite' ),
     'priority' => 11,
        )
    );
```

Than I added a section to it:

```
$wp_customize->add_section(
     'title_section', array(
     'title' => esc_html__( 'Main Screen Section', 'anvitest-lite' ),
     'panel' => 'anvitest-lite',
        )
    );
```

Up to this point, everything works fine. But in the section, I need to display four fields with contacts (mail, address and phone number). I create the fields:

```
/**************************email_field****************************/
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'email_field', array(
            'default'           => ''
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'title_section', array(
        'label'           => esc_html__( 'Enter E-mail', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        'section'         => 'title_section',
        'settings'        => 'email_field',
        'type'            => 'email',
        'description'     => esc_html__( 'Enter your mail in this field', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        )
    );
    /**************************phone_field****************************/
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'phone_field', array(
            'default'           => ''
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'title_section', array(
        'label'           => esc_html__( 'Enter Phone', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        'section'         => 'title_section',
        'settings'        => 'phone_field',
        'type'            => 'text',
        'description'     => esc_html__( 'Enter your phone in this field', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        )
    );
    /**************************adress_field****************************/
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'adress_field', array(
            'default'           => ''
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'title_section', array(
        'label'           => esc_html__( 'Enter Adress', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        'section'         => 'title_section',
        'settings'        => 'adress_field',
        'type'            => 'text',
        'description'     => esc_html__( 'Enter your adress in this field', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        )
    );
```

But from this only a field for entering an email address is displayed in this customizer. see screen: http://prntscr.com/nt891d . Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Here is the code:

```
 $wp_customize->add_panel(
        'anvitest-lite',[
            'title'           => esc_html__( 'Theme Options', 'anvitest-lite' ),
            'priority' => 11,
        ]
    );

    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'title_section', [
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Main Screen Section', 'anvitest-lite' ),
            'panel' => 'anvitest-lite',
            'priority'  => 200,   
        ]
    );


    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'email_field', array(
            'default'           => ''
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'email_field', array(
            'section'         => 'title_section',
            'type'            => 'email',
            'description'     => esc_html__( 'Enter your mail in this field', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        )
    );
    /**************************phone_field****************************/
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'phone_field', array(
            'default'           => ''
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'phone_field', array(
            'label'           => esc_html__( 'Enter Phone', 'anvitest-lite' ),
            'section'         => 'title_section',
            'type'            => 'text',
            'description'     => esc_html__( 'Enter your phone in this field', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        )
    );
    /**************************adress_field****************************/
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'adress_field', array(
            'default'           => ''
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'adress_field', array(
            'label'           => esc_html__( 'Enter Adress', 'anvitest-lite' ),
            'section'         => 'title_section',
            'type'            => 'text',
            'description'     => esc_html__( 'Enter your adress in this field', 'anvitest-lite' ),
        )
    );
```